# I'm trying to overlap a nav bar on top of an image

Tags: html, css

I've been playing with the margins of my  but it doesnt budge. I set the z-index to be larger for the nav  bar but it wont overlap on the image.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you, adapt to your needs:
HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
        </div>
        <img class="img-under">
    </body>
</html>
```

Css

```
.nav {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#000000;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
}
.img-under {
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  height:60px;
  width:200px;
}
```

Comment: I actually figured it out right now.
But thanks so much, Im gonna look at your method.